# Render Error with delivery option coming out at the bottom inside of to the side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an amazon checkout page. I want it to look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C9fA.png) where the product and the delivery option are side to side. But I keep getting this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPNl6.png) where the product is above and the delivery options are at the bottom. I don't know if this is an error with the CSS, HTML or JS I just want to fix it so I can finally finish my project. These are the files for the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Checkout</title>

    <!-- This code is needed for responsive design to work.
      (Responsive design = make the website look good on
      smaller screen sizes like a phone or a tablet). -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Load a font called Roboto from Google Fonts. -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Here are the CSS files for this page. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/shared/general.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/pages/checkout/checkout-header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/pages/checkout/checkout.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="checkout-header">
      <div class="header-content">
        <div class="checkout-header-left-section">
          <a href="amazon.html">
            <img class="amazon-logo" src="images/amazon-logo.png">
            <img class="amazon-mobile-logo" src="images/amazon-mobile-logo.png">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="checkout-header-middle-section">
          Checkout (<a class="return-to-home-link"
            href="amazon.html">3 items</a>)
        </div>

        <div class="checkout-header-right-section">
          <img src="images/icons/checkout-lock-icon.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="page-title">Review your order</div>

      <div class="checkout-grid">
        <div class="order-summary js-order-summary">
        </div>
        <div class="payment-summary">
          <div class="payment-summary-title">
            Order Summary
          </div>

          <div class="payment-summary-row">
            <div>Items (3):</div>
            <div class="payment-summary-money">$42.75</div>
          </div>

          <div class="payment-summary-row">
            <div>Shipping &amp; handling:</div>
            <div class="payment-summary-money">$4.99</div>
          </div>

          <div class="payment-summary-row subtotal-row">
            <div>Total before tax:</div>
            <div class="payment-summary-money">$47.74</div>
          </div>

          <div class="payment-summary-row">
            <div>Estimated tax (10%):</div>
            <div class="payment-summary-money">$4.77</div>
          </div>

          <div class="payment-summary-row total-row">
            <div>Order total:</div>
            <div class="payment-summary-money">$52.51</div>
          </div>

          <button class="place-order-button button-primary">
            Place your order
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="scripts/checkout.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
import {cart, removeFromCart} from '../data/cart.js';
import {products} from '../data/products.js';
import { formatCurrency } from './utils/money.js';

let cartSummaryHTML = ''; 

cart.forEach((cartItem) => {
    const productId = cartItem.productId;

    let matchingProduct;

    products.forEach((product) => {
        if (product.id === productId) {
            matchingProduct = product;
        }
    });

    console.log(matchingProduct);
    cartSummaryHTML += `  
    <div class="cart-item-container js-cart-item-container-${matchingProduct.id}">
        <div class="delivery-date">
            Delivery date: Tuesday, June 21
        </div>

        <div class="cart-item-details-grid">
            <img class="product-image" src="${matchingProduct.image}">

            <div class="cart-item-details">
                <div class="product-name">
                ${matchingProduct.name}
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    $${formatCurrency(matchingProduct.priceCents)}
                </div>
                <div class="product-quantity">
                    <span>
                        Quantity: <span class="quantity-label">${cartItem.quantity}</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="update-quantity-link link-primary">
                        Update
                    </span>
                    <span class="delete-quantity-link link-primary js-delete-link"
                    data-product-id="${matchingProduct.id}">
                        Delete
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="delivery-options">
            <div class="delivery-options-title">
                Choose a delivery option:
            </div>
            <div class="delivery-option">
                <input type="radio" checked class="delivery-option-input" name="delivery-option-${matchingProduct.id}">
                <div>
                    <div class="delivery-option-date">
                        Tuesday, June 21
                    </div>
                    <div class="delivery-option-price">
                        FREE Shipping
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="delivery-option">
                <input type="radio" class="delivery-option-input" name="delivery-option-${matchingProduct.id}">
                <div>
                    <div class="delivery-option-date">
                        Wednesday, June 15
                    </div>
                    <div class="delivery-option-price">
                        $4.99 - Shipping
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="delivery-option">
                <input type="radio" class="delivery-option-input" name="delivery-option-${matchingProduct.id}">
                <div>
                    <div class="delivery-option-date">
                        Monday, June 13
                    </div>
                    <div class="delivery-option-price">
                        $9.99 - Shipping
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `;
});

document.querySelector('.js-order-summary').innerHTML = cartSummaryHTML;

document.querySelectorAll('.js-delete-link').forEach((link)=> {
    link.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const productId = link.dataset.productId;
        removeFromCart(productId);

        const container = document.querySelector(`.js-cart-item-container-${productId}`);    
        container.remove();
    });
});
```

```
.main {
  max-width: 1100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;

  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;

  /* margin-left: auto;
     margin-right auto;
     Is a trick for centering an element horizontally
     without needing a container. */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.page-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.checkout-grid {
  display: grid;
  /* Here, 1fr means the first column will take
     up the remaining space in the grid. */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 350px;
  column-gap: 12px;

  /* Use align-items: start; to prevent the elements
     in the grid from stretching vertically. */
  align-items: start;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .main {
    max-width: 500px;
  }

  .checkout-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

.cart-item-container,
.payment-summary {
  border: 1px solid rgb(222, 222, 222);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 18px;
}

.cart-item-container {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.payment-summary {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .payment-summary {
    /* grid-row: 1 means this element will be placed into row
      1 in the grid. (Normally, the row that an element is
      placed in is determined by the order of the elements in
      the HTML. grid-row overrides this default ordering). */
    grid-row: 1;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
}

.delivery-date {
  color: rgb(0, 118, 0);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.cart-item-details-grid {
  display: grid;
  /* 100px 1fr 1fr; means the 2nd and 3rd column will
     take up half the remaining space in the grid
     (they will divide up the remaining space evenly). */
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 25px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .cart-item-details-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
    row-gap: 30px;
  }
}

.product-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 120px;

  /* margin-left: auto;
     margin-right auto;
     Is a trick for centering an element horizontally
     without needing a container. */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.product-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.product-price {
  color: rgb(177, 39, 4);
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-quantity .link-primary {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .delivery-options {
    /* grid-column: 1 means this element will be placed
       in column 1 in the grid. (Normally, the column that
       an element is placed in is determined by the order
       of the elements in the HTML. grid-column overrides
       this default ordering).
       
       / span 2 means this element will take up 2 columns
       in the grid (Normally, each element takes up 1
       column in the grid). */
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
}

.delivery-options-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.delivery-option {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 24px 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delivery-option-input {
  margin-left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delivery-option-date {
  color: rgb(0, 118, 0);
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.delivery-option-price {
  color: rgb(120, 120, 120);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.payment-summary-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.payment-summary-row {
  display: grid;
  /* 1fr auto; means the width of the 2nd column will be
     determined by the elements inside the column (auto).
     The 1st column will take up the remaining space. */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;

  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.payment-summary-money {
  text-align: right;
}

.subtotal-row .payment-summary-money {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

.subtotal-row div {
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.total-row {
  color: rgb(177, 39, 4);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;

  border-top: 1px solid rgb(222, 222, 222);
  padding-top: 18px;
}

.place-order-button {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;

  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Answer to my problem